# Munit suit failed when trying to build using Maven in the command prompt (DynamicEvaluateProcessor)

Tags: maven, mule4, munit

I have a problem when build Mule application outside anypoint studio using mvn clean test in command prompt

when i execute the command I got the error:

```
Message               : Error creating bean with name 'process-logic-service-flow': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#62fd718' of type [com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.DynamicEvaluateProcessor] while setting bean property 'messageProcessors' with key [3]; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#62fd718': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#5466c7bf' of type [com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.DynamicEvaluateProcessorParameters] while setting bean property 'parameters'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#5466c7bf': Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'annotations' of bean class [com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.DynamicEvaluateProcessorParameters]: Bean property 'annotations' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
Element               : process-order-api-Flow/processors/2/route/1/processors/0/route/1/processors/2 @ m4-logic-services:flows/process/process-order-api.xml:168 (Calling Process logic Service Flow)
Element DSL           : <flow-ref doc:name="Calling Process logic Service Flow" doc:id="90c6a060-8db7-4120-b0be-00c37e576b96" name="process-logic-service-flow"></flow-ref>
Error type            : MULE:UNKNOWN
FlowStack             : at process-order-api-Flow(process-order-api-Flow/processors/2/route/1/processors/0/route/1/processors/2 @ m4-logic-services:flows/process/process-order-api.xml:168 (Calling Process logic Service Flow))
at post:\order\searchFilter:application\json:logics-api-config(post:\order\searchFilter:application\json:logics-api-config/processors/1 @ m4-logic-services:flows/experience/experience-logic-services-api.xml:134 (Call process-order-api-Flow))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Root Exception stack trace:
org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: Invalid property 'annotations' of bean class [com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.DynamicEvaluateProcessorParameters]: Bean property 'annotations' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.createNotWritablePropertyException(BeanWrapperImpl.java:243)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.processLocalProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:426)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:278)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.setPropertyValue(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:266)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:77)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1714)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:312)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:131)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveManagedList(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:401)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:159)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1681)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1433)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:592)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.getBean(ObjectProviderAwareBeanFactory.java:78)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1105)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean.getReferencedProcessor(FlowRefFactoryBean.java:231)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean.getReferencedFlow(FlowRefFactoryBean.java:161)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1a3b6258.CGLIB$getReferencedFlow$2(<generated>)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1a3b6258$$FastClassByCGLIB$$7e361ccb.invoke(<generated>)
        at net.sf.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.dsl.spring.ObjectFactoryClassRepository.lambda$getObjectFactoryDynamicClass$1(ObjectFactoryClassRepository.java:125)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean$$EnhancerByCGLIB$$1a3b6258.getReferencedFlow(<generated>)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean$StaticFlowRefMessageProcessor.lambda$new$0(FlowRefFactoryBean.java:297)
        at org.mule.runtime.api.util.LazyValue.get(LazyValue.java:75)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean$StaticFlowRefMessageProcessor.apply(FlowRefFactoryBean.java:317)
        at org.mule.runtime.config.internal.factories.FlowRefFactoryBean$StaticFlowRefMessageProcessor.apply(FlowRefFactoryBean.java:291)
        at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
        at java.util.function.Function.lambda$andThen$1(Function.java:88)
        at reactor.core.* (1 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.* (1 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at reactor.core.* (1 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.chain.* (2 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at reactor.core.* (1 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.strategy.reactor.builder.ReactorPublisherBuilder$FluxBuilder.transform(ReactorPublisherBuilder.java:182)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.strategy.reactor.builder.ComponentProcessingStrategyReactiveProcessorBuilder.baseProcessingStrategyPublisherBuilder(ComponentProcessingStrategyReactiveProcessorBuilder.java:148)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.strategy.reactor.builder.ComponentProcessingStrategyReactiveProcessorBuilder.lambda$build$0(ComponentProcessingStrategyReactiveProcessorBuilder.java:118)
        at reactor.core.* (1 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.strategy.TransactionAwareStreamEmitterProcessingStrategyDecorator.lambda$null$6(TransactionAwareStreamEmitterProcessingStrategyDecorator.java:152)
        at reactor.core.* (14 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ReactiveInterceptionAction.proceed(ReactiveInterceptionAction.java:75)
        at org.mule.munit.mock.interception.MunitProcessorInterceptor.around(MunitProcessorInterceptor.java:129)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ProcessorInterceptorWrapper.around(ProcessorInterceptorWrapper.java:68)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.lambda$doAround$3(ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.java:95)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ExceptionUtils.tryExpecting(ExceptionUtils.java:224)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:1075)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.api.util.ClassUtils.withContextClassLoader(ClassUtils.java:993)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.doAround(ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.java:94)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.interceptor.ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.lambda$null$0(ReactiveAroundInterceptorAdapter.java:72)
        at reactor.core.* (95 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
        at reactor.core.* (9 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.* (2 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at reactor.core.* (13 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.rx.FluxSinkRecorder$DirectDelegate.next(FluxSinkRecorder.java:196)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.internal.rx.FluxSinkRecorder.next(FluxSinkRecorder.java:68)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.* (1 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at reactor.core.* (30 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenCompleteStage(CompletableFuture.java:778)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:2140)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.whenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:110)
        at reactor.core.* (98 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:760)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:736)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
        at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
        at reactor.core.* (12 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.* (2 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at reactor.core.* (1 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at org.mule.runtime.core.privileged.processor.chain.* (2 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at reactor.core.* (6 elements filtered from stack; set debug level logging or '-Dmule.verbose.exceptions=true' for everything)(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.doRun(AbstractRunnableFutureDecorator.java:113)
        at org.mule.service.scheduler.internal.RunnableFutureDecorator.run(RunnableFutureDecorator.java:54)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

********************************************************************************
```

**Caused by: com.mulesoft.mule.runtime.core.internal.processor.DynamicEvaluateProcessor: MUnit Tests Failed

**

but the MUnit test suites runs fine inside anypoint studio.

my pom file plugins and dependency:

```
<plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mule.tools.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>mule-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${mule.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <sharedLibraries>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                        <sharedLibrary>
                            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                        </sharedLibrary>
                    </sharedLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${munit.version}</version>
            <executions>
            <execution>
            <id>test</id>
            <phase>test</phase>
            <goals>
            <goal>test</goal>
            <goal>coverage-report</goal>
            </goals>
            </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
            <coverage>
            <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
            <formats>
            <format>html</format>
            </formats>
            </coverage>
            </configuration>
            </plugin> 
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>munit-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${munit.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                            <goal>coverage-report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <coverage>
                        <runCoverage>true</runCoverage>
                        <formats>
                            <format>html</format>
                        </formats>
                    </coverage>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <args>-parameters</args>
                    </compilerArgs>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-sockets-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-salesforce-connector</artifactId>
            <version>10.7.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>       
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>6.4.0.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-soapkit-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.11</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-apikit-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-validation-module</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-runner</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.13</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mulesoft.munit</groupId>
            <artifactId>munit-tools</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.13</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.modules</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-spring-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.6</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.4.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-db-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.11.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.weave</groupId>
            <artifactId>assertions</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
                <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.connectors</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-http-connector</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.23</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.9.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20230227</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mule.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>mule-java-module</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0</version>
            <classifier>mule-plugin</classifier>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

I'm using DynamicEvaluate to process the data, It looks like munit test suit is failing in DynamicEvaluateProcessor bean creation.

I have tried with mock the DynamicEvaluate component with the same values, then also I'm getting the same error message.

Any help would be gratefully appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Mule is it? Share the test. Probably unrelated but dependency `<groupId>org.mule</groupId>
<artifactId>mule-core</artifactId>
<version>3.8.0</version>` is wrong for Mule 4.x. At best it does nothing. This should not be in a Mule 4 project.

Comment: @aled, I have added the Mule version which I have used in Mule 4 application. Can you please check now?

Comment: That's not the Mule version. It is the version of your project.

Comment: I'm using 4.4.0 mule version <app.runtime>4.4.0</app.runtime>.

Answer (score 0):

It may be related to a fix in a later patch release of Mule 4.4.0. If Studio is using a patched runtime that would explain why it works there. Try changing the version in the pom to the latest patch. See https://docs.mulesoft.com/release-notes/mule-runtime/mule-4.4.0-release-notes to find the latest.

I recommend to upgrade the MUnit version too just in case and remove the `mule-core` dependency completely.